# How do I suppress this deprecated warning on a typealias in Kotlin with Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, deprecation-warning

Say I have this snippet in a kotlin file:

```kotlin
typealias GoodThing = Bad.Thing
fun thing(): Bad.Thing = GoodThing

@Deprecated("Deprecated")
sealed class Bad {

    @Deprecated("Deprecated")
    object Thing: Bad()
}
```

In Android Studio Arctic Fox, I get a deprecated warning on `GoodThing` in this line:

```kotlin
fun thing(): Bad.Thing = GoodThing
```

Which reads:
`typealias GoodThing = Bad.Thing' uses 'Thing', which is deprecated`

I want to suppress this warning.  But I can't seem to figure out how.  I have tried this, but it didn't work:

```kotlin
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
typealias GoodThing = Bad.Thing

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun thing(): Bad.Thing = GoodThing
```

What can I do to suppress this warning?

**NOTE:** Please  Assume I do not have access to modify `sealed class Bad`.  So setting `DeprecationLevel.HIDDEN` on `object Thing` is not possible.

Also I know this snippet looks odd, but I'm not interested in discussing the "why" of this code snippet.  I am simply asking if there is a way to suppress the warning in the snippet.  And if it is not possible, is that a bug in Android Studio?  Or is that expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out shortly after posting this:

```kotlin
@Suppress("TYPEALIAS_EXPANSION_DEPRECATION")
fun thing(): Bad.Thing = GoodThing
```

Comment: Hi @PhillyTheThrilly I am also facing same issue its not working for me.